# Merge Columns and Remove Duplication

Tags: python, file, merge, duplication

I have a input file that has data in 2 columns. I need to merge both the columns and remove the duplication. Any suggestions how to start with ? Thanks !

Input file

```
5045 2317
5045 1670
5045 2156
5045 1509
5045 3833
5045 1013
5045 3491
5045 32
5045 1482
5045 2495
5045 4280
5045 1380
5045 3998
```

Expected output

```
 5045 
 2317
 1670
 2156
 1509
 3833
 1013
 3491
 32
 1482
 2495
 4280
 1380
 3998
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No order does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the order:

```
from itertools import chain
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = list(chain.from_iterable(x.split() for x in f))
    with open("in.txt","w") as f1:
        for ind, line in enumerate(lines,1):
            if not line in lines[:ind-1]:
                f1.write(line+"\n")
```

output:

```
5045
2317
1670
2156
1509
3833
1013
3491
32
1482
2495
4280
1380
3998
```

If order does not matter:

```
from itertools import chain
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = set(chain.from_iterable(x.split() for x in f))
    with open("in.txt","w") as f1:
        f1.writelines("\n".join(lines))
```

If there is only one number repeated in the first column:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    col_1 = f.next().split()[0] # get first column number
    lines = set(x.split()[1] for x in f) # get all second column nums
    lines.add(col_1) # add first column num
    with open("in.txt","w") as f1:
        f1.writelines("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: This works great .. But when it comes to big files it takes time

Comment: how big are your files?

Comment: I have range of files from KB,MB and GB

Comment: I cannot think of any more efficient way than a set to removes dups, is the first column always repeated?

Comment: so we only need a single value for the first column, it will always only contain one repeated number?

Comment: what about the second column, is there duplication there?

Answer (score 1):

```
set1 = set()
set2 = set()
for line in myfile:
    a,b = line.strip().split()
    set1.add(int(a))
    set2.add(int(b))
set1.update(set2)
```

then write the contents of set1 to file.

Comment: why are you sorting and casting?

Comment: you will lose orders with set . can you grantee that 2317 print before 1670.

Comment: true, his expected output is not sorted. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the order of the rows in the output does matter. The output of the code below will exactly match your desired output (unlike answers that use `set`s, for example):

```
In [1]: with open("file.txt") as f, open("output.txt", "w") as out:
   ...:     arrs = [ l.rstrip().split() for l in f ] 
   ...:     vals = [ a for arr in arrs for a in arr ] # merge columns
   ...:     # restrict to first occurrence of each value (i.e. remove duplicates)
   ...:     uniqueVals = [ v for i, v in enumerate(vals) if vals.index(v) == i ]
   ...:     out.write("\n".join(uniqueVals))
```

This takes the input from a `"file.txt"` and outputs to `"output.txt"` by:

1. Loading the input file.
2. Merging the two columns.
3. Restricting to the first occurrence of each value.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.loadtxt('file_name',delimiter=' ')
>>> a=a.flatten()
>>> a=list(set(a))
>>> a
[32.0, 3491.0, 1380.0, 1509.0, 1670.0, 1482.0, 2156.0, 2317.0, 5045.0, 4280.0, 3833.0, 2495.0, 3998.0, 1013.0]
```